Como crear un modelo con varios objetos de otro modelo?
Estoy recapitulando mi trabajo en DJango luego de un tiempo y me encuentro con una situacuion en la que ocupo ayuda.
El caso es que tengo una tabla que tiene por nombre Carta_porte donde se definen roles como :

Autorizado_por
Remitente
Destinatario
Conductor

todas las anteriores son instancias del mismo modelo User de Django, se que es una relacion ManyToMany pero quiero tener acceso a cada uno de esos roles por separado a la hora de hacer los Insert/Update/Delete

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
